# Buying a .com for a domain whose .in I already have with site developed, can i share the hosting?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

I had recently bought a "somewebsite.in" domain and a hosting for it too, and had started development work on it. I have used wordpress on the site, so far no traffic is there on the site.

I am getting .com domain for the same domain name "somewebsite.com" soon, I am buying it from the person who owns it right now.

What do you suggest is the best thing to do ?

Should I redirect the .com domain to .in ? I want to target the .in (indian) audience for my website, Is there any way I can use the hosting I have taken for my .com domain ?

Will this affect SEO by any chance ? I am super confused and need some guidance on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You wait for some time your website get traffic, there is no problem with your website like domain name .in or .com etc. but your audience may don't like .in domain when they are from other country expect India. This problem face in starting when your website publish quality content visitor most like it as I make first .us then I also purchase .com.

both are redirect on same .com site there is no effect on traffic.